# Enable Software update feature in VLC source code

Tags: visual-c++, updates, libvlc

I am trying to include software update feature in my custom VLC source code. But the entire software update code is disabled. It can be enabled only when UPDATE_CHECK is defined. I tried defining UPDATE_CHECK but it didn't helped. Any suggestions would be helpful in this regard.